# iterating through a stringified json data in angularjs return undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to iterate through a stringified json data using angularjs but I am getting undefined on outputing the variables. My json format is shown below on picking from the console

```
{"data":[
{"id":1,"firstname":"jhfhfh","lastname":"hchch","middlename":null,"dob":"hhc","gender":"hhhhchch","nat":"chhch","phonenumber":null,"idn:"chch",
"email":"yuyu@yahoo.com","username":"cat","password":"password","country":"hshh","state":"hdhdh","city":"hdhdh","address":"area","confirmedEmail":null,"dateOfReg":"hhc"}],
"status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"/up","requestHeaders":{"Accept":"application/json"},
"params":{"email":"yuyu@yahoo.com"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"OK"}
```

here is my angular function

```
getData: function (email) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/up',
            requestHeaders: {Accept: 'application/json'},
            params: {email: email}
        }).then(function successCallback(res) {
            if (res.status == 204) {

            } else if (res.status == 200) {

                var myJSON = JSON.stringify(res);

                console.log(myJSON); //prints the data

                var variable = '';
                var name = '';
                angular.forEach(myJSON,function(item) { //attempting to do the iteration here
                    variable +=  item.email ;
                    name +=  item.username ;

                })

                alert(variable); //outputs undefined

            }
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    }
    }
```

how do I loop through the json data

Comment: Your response is already in json.you dont need to stringfy it.

Comment: with `.then` you need `res.data` instead of `res`. Also why are you stringifying it?

Comment: how do I loop over it then with the {"data":[

Comment: I am stringifying because res.email keeps outputing undefined. so I decided to stringify it

Comment: once, again, you need `res.data`, not `res`. So for your emails you need `res.data.email`

Comment: res.data.email returns undefined on alerting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong:

```
getData: function (email) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/up',
        requestHeaders: {Accept: 'application/json'},
        params: {email: email}
    }).then(function successCallback(res) {
        if (res.status == 204) {

        } else if (res.status == 200) {

            var myJSON = res.data; // <-- THIS IS WHAT I HAVE CHANGED

            console.log(myJSON); //prints the data

            var variable = '';
            var name = '';
            angular.forEach(myJSON,function(item) { //attempting to do the iteration here
                variable +=  item.email ;
                name +=  item.username ;

            })

            alert(variable); //outputs undefined

        }
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
}
}
```

Do `var myJSON = res.data;` and it'll work. Your `res.data` is an array, so iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse for parse string to JSON object,
And after if you have response.data as array you can use native forEach methods

Comment: Please provide an example for that.